# How to bind return values from stored procedures with Poco?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, odbc, poco-libraries

*Original objective*

I need to call stored procedures in SQL Server and have a way to determine the status code in the procedures from my calling C++ code to know if they succeeded or not. I do this with [Poco C++ Libraries](https://pocoproject.org).

*Failing method*

I have tried to return the status code from the procedures but can't find a way to bind the return value to my local variables successfully.

I use

- Microsoft SQL Server 2019
- Poco version: 1.9.4 with an ODBC-connection
- ODBC Driver: SQL Server Native Client 11.0

*Problem example*

I have created two stored procedures:

```
create procedure test1
as
    declare @result int;
    set @result = 5;
    return @result;
go
```

```
create procedure test2
as
    declare @result int;
    set @result = 5;
    select 'Hello World!' as message;
    return @result;
go
```

And tested them with the following lines of SQL in Micorsoft's SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

```
declare @result1 int;
exec @result1 = test1;
select @result1;
```

```
declare @result2 int;
exec @result2 = test2;
select @result2;
```

SSMS prints 5 in the first example and 'Hello World!' followed by 5 in the second example as expected.

However, when I run the following two examples with Poco I get different results.

```
Poco::Data::Statement statement( session );
std::int32_t result1 = -1;
statement << "exec ? = test1", out( result1 ), now;
```

```
Poco::Data::Statement statement( session );
std::int32_t result2 = -1;
statement << "exec ? = test2", out( result2 ), now;
```

In *test1* I successfully update the `result1` variable to the return code (*5*) but in *test2*, `result2` maintains its initial value of *-1*.

Can someone please explain how to successfully bind return codes from stored procedures with Poco? Or am I missing something trivial about SQL/ODBC?

*Update 1*

I have repeated the above examples, but using output parameters in the stored procedures, eg

```
create procedure test2B(@result int out)
```

And calling them with

```
statement << "exec test2B @result = ?", out( result2B ), now;
```

with the exact same behavior as when using return values.

*Update 2*

When using [ODBC Procedure Call Escape Sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/procedure-call-escape-sequence?view=sql-server-ver15) `{call myproc(?)}` I am able to return output parameters as long as the procedure does not contain a transaction.

```
create procedure test2B( @result int out )
as
    set @result = 5;
    select 'Hello World!' as message;
go
```

```
statement << "{call test2B(?)}", out(result2B), now; // Succeeds
```

```
create procedure test3( @result int out )
as
    set @result = 5;
    begin transaction;
    select 'Hello World!' as message;
    commit transaction;
go
```

```
statement << "{call test3(?)}", out(result3), now; // Fails
```

My only working strategy so far is to append a result column to my result sets.

Poco documentation:
[Poco::Data::Session](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Data.Session.html),
[Poco::Data::Statement](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Data.Statement.html)

Comment: You might be able to use the copy by value version, `bind`.  See the description here: https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Data.Binding.html